# Is there a generalisation of Yoneda embedding to toposes?

Tags: category-theory

The Yoneda lemma says that for a presheaf $F\in \hat{A}$, we have $F(a)\backsimeq \hat{A}[h_a,F]$ where $h_a:=A[-,a]$.

Now toposes are 'thought' of as a generalised category of sets.

So, for a topos $S$, shouldn't we then have a Yoneda lemma for a presheaf 'based' on $S$, ie a cofunctor $F:A^{op} \rightarrow S$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathbf{Set}$ is special because it is the category in which hom-objects live. Thus one should instead look at $\mathcal{V}$-enriched categories and $\mathcal{V}$-enriched presheaves for a symmetric monoidal closed category $\mathcal{V}$; and sure enough, there is a $\mathcal{V}$-enriched Yoneda lemma for $\mathcal{V}$-enriched natural transformations. You can take $\mathcal{V}$ to be a topos if you like, but not every category can be turned into a $\mathcal{V}$-enriched category.